# Paragraph setting with figures

Tags: paragraphs

I wish that all my paragraphs will start in the same place, but when I add figures, the seem to shift them.
[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[top=0.59in,bottom=0.59in,left=0.59in,right=0.59in]{geometry}
%% packges not from aps
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true,
  urlcolor     = red, 
  linkcolor    = black, 
  citecolor   = black 
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

   \renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{My section}

Exploring the sand with big tools.\\
\begin{figure}[htbp!] 
\centerline{
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sand.jpg}}
\caption{\footnotesize{picture of sand.}}
\label{fig:dis_3}
\end{figure} 
Testing our tools shows success.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Paragraphes in TeX are done by a blank line or by the command `\par`. On the other site you don't need a floating environment. You are loading the package `float` which provides the placement specifier `H`.

Comment: never end a paragraph with `\\ ` tex will warn you about underfull hbox with badness 10000 which is maximum badness, also do not use `\centerline` in latex, and size commands such as `\footnotesize` do not take an argument and should not be used in `\caption` (for example it will mess up the list of figures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[top=0.59in,bottom=0.59in,left=0.59in,right=0.59in]{geometry}
%% packges not from aps
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true,
  urlcolor     = red, 
  linkcolor    = black, 
  citecolor   = black 
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{My section}

Exploring the sand with big tools. \\ Testing our tools shows success.
\begin{figure}[htbp!] 
\centerline{
\noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}}
\caption{\footnotesize{picture of sand.}}
\label{fig:dis_3}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: cheers, did not notice it